# Issue with rendering template index.html

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on Flask app that will get the data from my sqlite3 database and push it to the index.html. For some reason i am getting the error when I execute the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
import sqlite3
# Retrieve data from database
def getData():
    conn=sqlite3.connect('../Sensors.db')
    curs=conn.cursor()
    for row in curs.execute("SELECT * FROM BME_DATA ORDER BY TIME_STAMP DESC LIMIT 1"):
        Time = str(row[1])
        Temperature = row[2]
        Gas = row[3]
        Humidity = row[4]
        Pressure = row[5]
        Altitude = row[6]

    conn.close()
    return Time, Temperature, Gas, Humidity, Pressure, Altitude
# main route 
@app.route("/")
def index():    
    Time, Temperature, Gas, Humidity, Pressure, Altitude = getData()
    templateData = {
        'Time': Time,
        'Temperature': Temperature,
        'Gas': Gas,
        'Humidity': Humidity,
        'Pressure': Pressure,
        'Altitude': Altitude
    }
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=False)
```

The flask app is located ad BMEWebServer folder. And the structure I have looks like this:

```
BMEWebServer/appBMEWebServer.py
BMEWebServer/templates/style.css
BMEWebServer/static/index.html
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
    >>> %Run appBMEWebServer.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2019-03-01 01:45:32,774] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Sensors_Database/BMEWebServer/appBMEWebServer.py", line 30, in index
    return render_template('static/index.html', **templateData)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 133, in render_template
    return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 851, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 812, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 774, in _load_template
    cache_key = self.loader.get_source(self, name)[1]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 57, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 85, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: static/index.html
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2019 01:45:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2019 01:45:34] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually your `css` file and `html` need to be exchanged. The correct structure should be:

```
BMEWebServer/appBMEWebServer.py
BMEWebServer/templates/index.html
BMEWebServer/static/style.css
```

Comment: i tried switching and that didnt work ether. it gave me same error.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the way you have structured your files. Just get the index.html  file to Tue right folder that is BMEWebServer/templates/index.html  and do the same for the CSS which means BMEWebServer/static/styles.css . Jinja is very smart to render whatever is in the right path.

Comment: I have tried putting them in the folders as you and Sraw suggested but that didnt work. It gives me the same error message.

Answer (score -1):

Well thank you both Sraw and Douglas, you were right. It actually did work when i did change the files in correct directories, i actually had additional issue where my folder templates was named without "s" at the end. Once i renamed I got the page up.
Thank you so much